# ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE C# equivalent

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
const UINT WM_ISCP_FRAME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_ISCP_FRAME");

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CScannerDemoDlg, CDialog)
//more code
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(WM_ISCP_FRAME,WindowMessageIscpFrame)
//more code
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CScannerDemoDlg::WindowMessageIscpFrame(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
    // code 
}
```

From what I have learned the `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE` is used to register to listen to certain events. What I have not been able to determine is how to translate this code to C#?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using WPF or winforms

Comment: Is [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ac117935-6f0d-4378-9521-2670eba49679) what you looking for?

Comment: @parapurarajkumar I want to write a wrapper for a dll, so would like to keep it UI agnostic.

Comment: In your C++ code CDialog MessagePump is dispatching the message to your function. You need a message  pump on the C# sharp side as well

Comment: This style of programming isn't really used in WinForms or WPF. What are you trying to translate?

Answer (score 1):

[Application.AddMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) should help your C# winform application listen to win32 system wide messges

Answer (score 1):

You can handle Windows message by overriding Form.WndProc Method. See code sample here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.aspx

If you need to send/post Windows messages, use PInvoke with SendMessage/PostMessage API.